# Attaching to ActiveX Events in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, activex, internet-explorer-9, web-standards

I have embeded an ActiveX control via an HTML `<option>` element in Internet Explorer that plays video from a Cisco video server.

To make the player play I write a callback function for the ActiveX control's *onPlayerLoaded* event.

The code I have works in IE 7 - 9, but only when I use Microsoft's proprietary *attachEvent* function.

JavaScript example:

```
if(this.axClient.attachEvent) 
    { this.axClient.attachEvent("onPlayerLoaded", onPlayerLoadedEventHandler); }
```

The standard's nazi in me really wants to use *addEventListener* instead like so ...

```
if(this.axClient.addEventListener)
    { this.axClient.addEventListener("onPlayerLoaded", onPlayerLoadedEventHandler, false); }
else if(this.axClient.attachEvent) 
    { this.axClient.attachEvent("onPlayerLoaded", onPlayerLoadedEventHandler); }
```

(Starting with IE 9, *addEventListener* is supported.)

Unfortunately when I use *addEventListener* the callback function never gets called.

I do not have a lot of experience with consuming ActiveX controls, so I'm assuming there are some nuances about them that I might be missing.

Given that ActiveX is a Microsoft proprietary technology is it a fair assumption that we should continue to use *attachEvent* instead of *addEventListener* with them? (Is there something inherent in ActiveX that forces us to continue using *attachEvent?*)

Or is this something the publisher of the AciveX control can remedy? (For example, are there new practices for ActiveX that take advantage of IE 9 more standard-friendly nature.)

Or given that ActiveX is proprietary, should I just not worry too much about standards with them ...? ;)

Comment: I don't know if this matters as I'm not big on scripting, but I noticed that when you use addEventListener you have a lower case 'L' in "onPlayerloaded" and an upper case 'L' when using attachEvent "onPlayerLoaded".

Comment: @Maurizo that was just a typo in my question, which I just corrected. It *would* matter in JavaScript as the language is case sensitive. Good eye!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked into this same question while trying to make addEventListener work with my [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) plugins. Since FireBreath plugins work on all major browsers, I was excited that in IE9 addEventListener support would make it so that everything could work exactly the same.

Imagine my shock when I discovered that none of the APIs on the plugin/activex control -- none of them -- were called or notified in any way when addEventListener was called on the object. attachEvent uses an interface on the ActiveX control called Connection Points, and on Firefox we have to implement the addEventListener and removeEventListener methods ourselves, but on IE9 it just intercepts those calls, doesn't return an error, and they disappear into the void.

{sarcasm}Amazing! Way to go Microsoft!{/sarcasm}

Comment: Great explanation. Do you have a reference for the "Connection Points" you mention? (I'm assuming it's a fancy name for the ActiveX interfaces one has to implement when writing an ActiveX control.)

Comment: Connection Points are grouped with the things that you really have to dig through before you'll understand fully how to use them.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms694318(v=vs.85).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683857(v=vs.85).aspx give you the microsoft docs for the interface. https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/ActiveXCore/JSAPI_IDispatchEx.h#L193 is FireBreath's implementation of connection points.

Comment: I was stumbled on addEventListener, too. IE9 accept it, but ActiveX events are not called. It seems **.attachEvent** is the only way to associated ActiveX events, IE only. Of course, ActiveX is IE only.